# Checking Multiple Boxes by clicking image with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website that I need to check/uncheck several boxes in an HTML form that is formatted in a table.  I am generating the code with PHP so I can change the IDs of the elements as needed.  Currently each column heading has a picture of a hero.  When that picture is clicked, I would like to uncheck all boxes in that column.  I don't currently have any javascript/jquery running on this page but I'm willing to embed whatever is needed to get the desired result.  In addition, I would also like to add the ability to check/uncheck melee heroes or ranged heroes.

This is my header row with the images:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdleft">Team A</td>
    <td><img id="1img" title="Adagio" src="images/heroes/adagio.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="2img" title="Ardan" src="images/heroes/ardan.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="3img" title="Catherine" src="images/heroes/catherine.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="4img" title="Celeste" src="images/heroes/celeste.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="5img" title="Glaive" src="images/heroes/glaive.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="6img" title="Joule" src="images/heroes/joule.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="7img" title="Koshka" src="images/heroes/koshka.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="8img" title="Krul" src="images/heroes/krul.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="9img" title="Petal" src="images/heroes/petal.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="10img" title="Ringo" src="images/heroes/ringo.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="11img" title="Saw" src="images/heroes/saw.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="12img" title="Skaarf" src="images/heroes/skaarf.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="13img" title="Taka" src="images/heroes/taka.png"></td>
    <td><img width="50px" id="25img" title="Vox" src="images/heroes/vox.png"></td>
</tr>
```

And here is the first row of checkboxes:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="player[]" type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Player1" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="1check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input id="2check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="2"></td>
    <td><input id="3check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="3"></td>
    <td><input id="4check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="4"></td>
    <td><input id="5check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="5"></td>
    <td><input id="6check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="6"></td>
    <td><input id="7check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="7"></td>
    <td><input id="8check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="8"></td>
    <td><input id="9check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="9"></td>
    <td><input id="10check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="10"></td>
    <td><input id="11check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="11"></td>
    <td><input id="12check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="12"></td>
    <td><input id="13check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="13"></td>
    <td><input id="25check" checked type="checkbox" name="p1[]" value="25"></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the full code for the table:

https://jsfiddle.net/beeqeay9/

Comment: can't understand your question properly. You may try adding onclick() function call in img tag and write a java script function to uncheck the check boxes of a column.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You are right, you need to use JavaScript to get the desired result. But few people will be willing to help you if you don't show what you tried. Please do some research, try the different methods you find, and if you still have a problem, edit your question with this code so we have a base to work on.

Comment: ... and format your code in a readable manor!

Comment: Thank you for reformatting.  This is my first SO post, wasn't quite sure how to make the code work at first, so when I finally got it right I just went with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know that IDs must be unique. You should use classes for your checkboxes. Here is a method, not requiring any external library:

```
// Grab your heroes
var heroes = document.querySelectorAll('table img');

// Attach a click event listener to each hero
for(var i=0, l=heroes.length; i<l; i++){
    heroes[i].addEventListener('click', toggleHero);
}

function toggleHero(){
    // Grab the index from the id
    var index = parseInt( this.id, 10 );
    // Get all checkboxes with a corresponding class
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(index + 'check');
    // If there are none, exit the function
    if(!checkboxes){ return false; }
    // Get the state of the first one
    var checked = checkboxes[0].checked;
    // Set all the checkboxes to the opposite state
    for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l; i++){
        checkboxes[i].checked = !checked;
    }
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

---

jQuery version *(shorter, but why load a 100kB library just for this?)*

```
$('table img').click(function(){
    var index = parseInt( this.id, 10 );
    var checked = $('.' + index + 'check').eq(0).is(':checked');
    $('.' + index + 'check').prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: blex thank you for this.  I will try it tonight.  However, in your jQuery version, the final hero checkbox doesn't work (Vox).  And props to you for getting the images!  See you in the Fold...

Comment: @xmaveric Sorry I got carried away and didn't calculate the index correctly. I just fixed it. Good luck to you, summoner.

Comment: the script is working!  At first it was not working because I included in the HEAD tag, but once I moved it into the body below the form it worked like a charm!  Can you help with the second part of my question... selecting/deslecting melee or ranged heroes?  I do have them tagged as such in my db query so I can output that somewhere in the image tag if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use id for logic.. If you want do something else with this checkbox after in addiction you can't because id are already used for something..

I prefere use data-attribute like on this example : https://jsfiddle.net/dk71qjz6/3/ (work only for first, i didn't take time to copy/past for each columns)

I have added `data-img-id` on each `img` tag, and a `data-ref-id` on each checkbox. And this jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Image clicked
    $('img').click(function(){
        // Get ref id
        var ref_id = $(this).attr('data-img-id');
        // Uncheck all ref checkbox
        $('input[data-ref-id=' + ref_id + ']').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Arthur -  do you have any idea why this not working in fiddle: $('#1img').click(function(){
    $('#1check').attr('checked', false);
    )};

Comment: #1 - Have you add jQuery on Framework list (to the right) ? #2 - Don't forget to put a `$(document).ready(function{ /***/ })` listener too. #3 - And don't use `attr()` function to uncheck but `prop()` https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: And you know you can't use the same ID on multiple tags. You have to use class attribute `.1check` instead of `#1check`

Comment: I tried all: can you please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ohhe8gc/1/    and try to figure it out, pls

Comment: You have inverse `)};` and `});` It's working here : https://jsfiddle.net/5ohhe8gc/4/ but for the 3th time : ID can't be reuse multiple time, so it's only working for the first one

Comment: Use my first example on the reply with `data-attribute` to get the best result. ID and Class are used for CSS not for the logic

Comment: @arther, classes are used all the time for dom manipulation logic...that doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yeah but data attribute are added to create a separation between logic and design. But sure, it's working with classes

Answer (score 0):

Can use indexing

```
$('td img').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).parent().index();
    $('tr').find('td:eq('+idx+') input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6vL6301q/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: As you can see on your demo, it's only work for the first checkbox on the column cause an ID can't be reuse multiple time

Comment: updated with indexing approach so repeating ID's become irrelevant